# Spring JPA with pageable and subquery causing query syntax error

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring Data Repository defined as given below:

```
public interface InvoiceRepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Long> {
   @Query(value = "select i.id as id,  " +
            "i.invoiceStatus as invoiceStatus, " +
            "(select sum(r.id) from Invoice r ) as paid " +
            "from Invoice i ")
    Page<InvoiceQuery> getInvoicesByStatusAndName(Pageable pageable);

}
```

The subquery given above is not the real one, but this simple query helps reproduce the the problem.

When my springboot(2.4.5) application comes up, I get  the following exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting EOF,
> found ')' near line 1, column 62 [select count(r) from
> com.anish.webacc.orm.entities.Invoice r ) as paid from
> com.anish.webacc.orm.entities.Invoice i ]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]

Now if i change

```
Page<InvoiceQuery> getInvoicesByStatusAndName(Pageable pageable);
```

to

```
List<InvoiceQuery> getInvoicesByStatusAndName(Pageable pageable);
```

then it works perfectly (without the paging part).

InvoiceQuery is a projection interface -

```
public interface InvoiceQuery {
    Long getId();
    InvoiceStatus getInvoiceStatus();
    Double getPaid();
}
```

It appears that the query generated is incorrect - for some reason i suspect that the paratheses in the subquery is causing the issue. If i remove the subquery i dont have an issue

This is the first time i am trying to do pagination so i maybe doing doing something really silly here  - any help will be appreciated.

thx
-anish

Comment: Why would you need a subquery for that? Also that subquery is weird why a `sum` on the `id` of  a table?

Comment: I agree, the subquery is trivial and silly, but it should still work!  The real subquery is complex but puuting it here is not necessary - this simple query highlights the problem.

Comment: @anish the issue is with count() query, it is not able to derive it when you use inner query.
Check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is when you are using inner queries Spring data JPA is not able to derive the count query. See when you want return type as Page , Page - has total pages and total elements as the two things it returns along with the Paginated result.

```
   int getTotalPages();

    long getTotalElements();
```

So to get these two things that is total elements with your conditions and total pages by given pagesize it has to derive a count() query, in your case it is unable to derive that count() query. You can explicitly specify the count query in your "@Query" annotation.  Like below

```
  @Query(value = "select new com.example.package.InvoiceQuery(i.id as id,i.invoiceStatus as invoiceStatus,(select sum(r.id) from Invoice r ) as paid ) from Invoice i",
 countQuery = "select count(*) from Invoice")
    Page<InvoiceQuery> getInvoicesByStatusAndName(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucia. As suspected, it looks like a bug in Spring Data - will file a bug there. I was not aware of the ability to provide a countQuery. Thanks for that info. My query is pretty big with quite a few where clauses, which i now have to repeat in the countQuery. That will be a pain to do but atleast i have something.

Answer (score 0):

countQuery is the best way but it means one more transaction to database, and may cost big up to how big data you look for in DB

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).